# Android: Modifying Car UX Restrictions by overlaying car_ux_restrictions_map.xml

Tags: android, xml, overlay

I am trying to disable all car UX restrictions by overlaying `<android_source>/packages/services/Car/service/res/xml/car_ux_restrictions_map.xml`.

I created `<vendor-path>/overlay/packages/services/Car/service/res/xml/car_ux_restrictions_map.xml` and added baseline restrictions for all drive modes in this file.

I also created `<vendor_path>/overlay/packages/services/Car/service/res/values/attrs.xml`, basically copied it over from `<android_source>/packages/services/Car/service/res/values/attrs.xml`.

However when I run my Android emulator and try to change drive modes, `CarUxRestrictionsConfigurationXmlParser.java` can't seem to read `R.styleable.UxRestrictions_Restrictions_uxr` and ends up setting restrictions on all drive modes to fully restricted, which further ends up locking my emulator UI for all drive modes.

Anybody know what might be the issue here? Do I need to make an AndroidManifest.xml, create and install an APK, etc.?

Comment: did you get anything with work out? Seems like system is getting into fully_restriction mode if moving, you can also edit the car_ux_restrictions_map.xml parameters.